# How to import a SASS file?

Tags: sass

I'm trying to use multiple variables accross my differents files, but I got an error saying `Undefined variable`.

**The example:**

*base.scss*

```css
$dark-blue: #031f60;
$blue: #36b2e6;
$dark-grey: #747577;
```

*center.scss*

```css
@use 'base';

p {
    color: $dark-blue;
}
```

I specifically used `@use` because SASS website mentioned that it will be deprecated in the future.

Answer (score 1):

`@use` only works with dart-sass so far, nonetheless,

The naming scheme for files that you want to include should have an underscore `_` at the start of the file name.

for example if anyone wants to include a variables file they should name it as `_variables.scss` rather than `variables.scss`.

In your case, change the name of `base.scss` to `_base.scss` and it should work as long as they are in the same folder/path given is correct.

Comment: By the way, there are not in the same directory, but in the example, it didn't mentionned it.

Comment: @Brice can you update your question with the folders in which your files are in? and what did you update in your code?